# Find all intial values for $\displaystyle y'-\frac{y}{2}=2 \cos t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y(t)$ satisfy the equation $$\displaystyle y'-\frac{y}{2}=2 \cos t$$ then find all the initial values $y(0)=y_0$ such that  $$\displaystyle a) \lim_{t\to \infty} y(t)>0$$ $$\displaystyle b) \lim_{t\to \infty} y(t)<0$$ and  $$\displaystyle c) \lim_{t\to \infty} y(t)$$ does not exists.

After solving for $y(t)$ I got $$\displaystyle y(t)=\frac{-4}{5}\cos t+\frac{8}{5}\sin t  +(y_0+\frac{4}{5})e^{\frac{t}{2}}$$
so I see $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to \infty} y(t)$ always does not exists because of $\cos , \sin$ expressions. So why does part a) and b) makes sense?

Comment: Your equation is right but questions $a)$ and $b)$ are related to the **sign** of the limit, not to the value of the limit.

Comment: For $y_0<-\frac{4}{5}$ $\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)<0$, for $y_0>-\frac{4}{5}$ $\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)>0$. For $y_0=-\frac{4}{5}$ the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Apart from (?) typos $\lim_{y\to \infty}$ instead of $\lim_{t\to \infty}$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, but if limit does not exists for any $y_0$ how can we talk about sign of limit?

Comment: @RainiervanEs you mean $\frac{-4}{5}$ instead of $\frac{4}{5}$

Comment: Suppose $y_0=0$ and a very large value of $t$; what is $y(t)$ looking like ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici it will be unbounded

Comment: Yes ... but positive !

Comment: see my answer, does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The limit doesn't exist only in one case: when $y_0=-\frac{4}{5}$, because in this case you have:

$$y(t)=\frac{-4}{5}\cos t+\frac{8}{5}\sin t$$

When $y_0>-\frac{4}{5}$ you have something greater than zero near $e^{\frac{t}{2}}$, so the limit is $+\infty$. When $y_0<-\frac{4}{5}$ you have something smaller than zero near $e^{\frac{t}{2}}$, so the limit is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y(t)=\frac{-4}{5}\cos t+\frac{8}{5}\sin t  +(y_0+\frac{4}{5})e^{\frac{t}{2}}$$
Note that:
$$\left|\frac{-4}{5}\cos t+\frac{8}{5}\sin t\right|\le\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{5}$$ 
So,

a) Worst case:$$\lim_{t\to\infty}(y_0+\frac{4}{5})e^{\frac{t}{2}}\ge\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{5}\\
(y_0+\frac45)>0\implies y_0>-\frac45$$ 
Work similiarly for others...

Comment: why a downvote?